# Trouble With SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I'm creating a fantasy football application, I'm reading in a text file in to my MYSQL database in the following format (my database is all populated):

```
FirstName LastName TeamName OpposingTeam Date (passing|rushing|fieldgoal) (FirstName LastName)?
```

The trailing name syntax "(FirstName LastName)?" means that this information may or may not be in the column. It's only present in the case of a passing touchdown and represents the quarterback who threw the ball.

Similarly, the syntax "(passing|rushing|fieldgoal)" just means that one of these specific values will be present.

Here's the schema for my database:

```
Player
    id: INT, primary key
    first: CHAR(25), first name of player
    last: CHAR(25), last name of player
    team: INT, foreign key to Team table

Team
    id: INT, primary key
    name: CHAR(25), single word name of team

Game
    id: INT, primary key
    tid1: INT, foreign key to Team table
    tid2: INT, foreign key to Team table
    date: YYYY-MM-DD

GameTeam
    id: INT, primary key
    GameID: INT, foreign key to Game table
    TeamID: INT, foreign key to Team table

Score
    id: INT, primary key
    game_id: INT, foreign key to Game table
    player_id: INT, foreign key to Player table
    passer_id: INT, foreign key to Player table
    score_type: enum['pass', 'rush', 'fg'], number of rushing touchdowns
```

In my app, a field goal is worth 3 points, and a passing/rushing touchdown is worth 7 points.

I am trying to come up with SQL queries that will help me get the following information:

How many touchdowns did Peyton Manning score or pass when he played against Miami?

List all the games (date and opposing team) that Tennessee won.

How many rushing touchdowns did Reggie Bush score in October?

I'm having a lot of trouble writing the queries that will help me get this information. Could someone please help me?

For clarification: everything is a CHAR(25), except for (passing|rushing|fieldgoal), which is an enum, and the Date which is in the form YYYY-MM-DD.

EDIT: Here's a pastebin with some of my data: http://pastebin.com/npKB5gQa

Comment: What do you have so far, and what are you struggling with?

Comment: And so far, you've tried...?  Also, why on earth would you design your schema like this if you have these specific queries in mind and no idea as to how you'd go about designing them?

Comment: I have my database all set up (including the table and data populated). I'm simply trying to run a query on my table to get the information in the 3 questions above.

Comment: I'm pretty new with databases and SQL.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Please, don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You really need to read up on normalization, this design is not going to work well for querying.

Comment: @HLGEM, it's completely normalized now!

Comment: show us the create tables for these, not typed like a human. Wanna set if from the box

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your design and create a separate table with the players data (firstname, lastname, etc.), teams, and so forth. And then reference the players/teams by ID on your PlayerRecord  table.

Comment: Hey, @carlosb. I just normalized my database. Could you take a look now?

Comment: your table GameTeam is not necessary as on table Game you already have the game_id plus both teams id's

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it then. I included a pastebin with some of my data for my app. How would I list all the games (including the date and opposing team) that Tennessee won?

Comment: with your current structure you could do something like this:

Comment: select 
 t1.name as team1,
 t2.name as team2,
 g.id as game_id,
 g.date as game_date
from game g
left outer join team t1 ON t1.id = g.tid1
left outer join team t2 ON t2.id = g.tid2
where
 t1.name = 'Tennessee' or t2.name = 'Tennessee'

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the requirement for Tennessee to have won. As for that, I would suggest you to save the final game score on the Game table so you don't have to do sums every time you want to see who won.

Comment: I can't believe that even with my schema simplified and normalized this much, the SQL has to look that messy. Are there anyways I could combat this? Also, how would I find out how many rushing touchdowns Reggie Bush scored in October, and how many touchdowns Peyton Manning scored or passed when he played against Miami?

Comment: thank you so much for your help btw! I'll be sure to give you a check once I've managed to get this bug/roadblock figured out.

Comment: how would you modify the SQL you suggested to include Tennessee winning?

Comment: I think you should first optimise your database design before jumping into queries. For instance, for you to determine now what team won, you first need to sum all of the points separately from both teams and then do a comparison. This is very inefficient. Specially if you want to run a query on multiple games. Ideally you would have the final results on the game table so you can use both results for comparison

Comment: I'm not particularly worried about efficiency with this app (at least not now), because I really just need the query for it to work. How would I solve the Tennessee problem with my current design?